# How to compute $\sin{(\pi x)}$ about $\frac12$ in taylor series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

The correct answer is supposed to be $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\pi^{2n}(x-\frac12)^n$ which I don't understand. Since the function is about $x=\frac12$, so $(x-\frac12)^n$ is good. But $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\pi^{2n}(x-\frac12)^n$ is supposed to be the Taylor expansion for $\cos(\pi(x-\frac12))$. How do you get such answer?

Comment: Isn't $\sin$ equal to $\cos$ shifted by half a pie?

Comment: Just see this $\sin\pi x = \sin( \pi(x-1/2)  +\pi/2).      $

Answer (score 1):

$\sin \pi x=\sin [\pi (x-1/2)+\pi /2]=\cos [\pi (x-1/2)],$ because $\sin (z+\pi /2)=\cos z.$

Comment: Well, what if it is about $\frac14$, so $\sin{\pi x}=\sin{[\pi (x-\frac14)+\frac{\pi}{4}]}=$something?

Comment: If a function $f$ is equal to its power series expansion about $x_0$ then $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((x-x_0)^n/n!)(D^nf)(x_0)$ where $D^nf$ is the $n$th derivative of $f.$ ($D^0f=f$). With $x_0=\pi /4$ and $f(x)=\sin x$ this is easy to compute because the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ and the deriv. of $\cos$  is $-\sin$.